# Why didn't C++20 provide range/constrained versions of algorithms from <numeric>?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/numeric), all numeric algorithms under header `<numeric>` didn't get `ranges` versions in C++20. Are there reasons?

Comment: The proposals to add this just didn't make it through the standardization process in time for c++20. They'll be added eventually.

Comment: There's a lot of things to rangify. If that had been a condition for adding ranges, they very likely would not have made it into C++20.

Comment: @cigien, so the parallel version of C++20 range-based algorithms will also be added eventually?

Comment: Assuming there are no issues with those features, and there are people willing to take the time to write these proposals, then sure :)

Comment: Are you asking about constrained, range-based, and/or parallelised versions? It's becoming less clear. The existing non-range ones could in theory be constrained using concepts, and paralellism is orthogonal to whether or not the algorithm is range.based.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1813r0.pdf